# When archive object in the func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) method crashed with swift enum in real revice

Tags: ios, swift, enums, archive

In my `singleton` class, I have a `swift` enum here:

```
import UIKit

enum UserType {
    case terant  // 
    case normalUser  // 
    case normalUserFinancialer  // 
}

@objc(UserStaticSwift)
class UserStaticSwift:NSObject, NSCoding {
```

The reported `error`:

With the `console` log:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

In the `encode`:

```
func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    
    aCoder.encode(islogin, forKey: "islogin")
    aCoder.encode(type!, forKey: "type")  // crash here in real device 
    aCoder.encode(forOcType, forKey: "forOcType")
    aCoder.encode(username, forKey: "username")
    aCoder.encode(password, forKey: "password")
    aCoder.encode(userId, forKey: "userId")
```

The `code` here I archive my `userStatic`:

```
    userStatic.addUserInfo(type: userStatic.type!, dic: userInfoDic, closure: { (void) in
            
                // success then archive `userStatic`
                let paths:NSArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true) as NSArray
                let path = paths.firstObject
                let homePath = "\(path)/\(Global.archive_userStaticData)"
                
                let _ = NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(userStatic, toFile: homePath)
                
            })
```

My `debug` when `archiveRootObject`:

The `console` log:

```
(lldb) po NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true) as NSArray

error: Couldn't materialize: couldn't get the value of void: extracting data from value failed

error: errored out in DoExecute, couldn't PrepareToExecuteJITExpression
(lldb) po homePath

error: Couldn't materialize: couldn't get the value of void: extracting data from value failed

error: errored out in DoExecute, couldn't PrepareToExecuteJITExpression
```

I have tested in `simulator` and `device`, in the `simulator` the issue not exist, in real `device` the issue comes out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this for your Question

```
func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(type.rawValue, forKey: "type")
}
```

**For More Information**

Let Discuss this problem in details

For example, this is my Enum:

```
enum PieceType : Int {
    case empty
    case notEmpty
}
```

And this is my Object which is child of `NSObject`

```
class Piece: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var islogin: Bool
    var type: PieceType
    var username: String!
    var password: String!

    override init() {
        islogin = false
        type = PieceType.empty
        username = ""
        password = ""
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        islogin = aDecoder.decodeBool(forKey: "islogin")
        type = PieceType(rawValue: aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "type") as! Int)!
        username = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "username") as! String
        password = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "password") as! String

    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(islogin, forKey: "islogin")
        aCoder.encode(type.rawValue, forKey: "type")
        aCoder.encode(username, forKey: "username")
        aCoder.encode(password, forKey: "password")

    }

}
```

When you call  `NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(::)` it will call `func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder)` method and convert your `NSObject` to Data And when you try to Unarchive your object it will call `init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` method and convert Data to `NSObject` by using Key.

But in `Enum` case you can not encode `enum` directly B'Coz it is User Define data type but `rawValue` is must be inbuilt data type like Int, String,Float.....So on.
that's why when you try to encode `enum` you need to use `rawValue`

I Hope you will get point.

Comment: @jinesh Vadadoriya I tested, in device do not report error now, but could you edit your answer more detail ? such as in the `enum UserType {` , you should edit it to be more detail. Here I know how to do with detail , but othere do not know should edit the `enum`.

Comment: sure,let me try to explain more

Comment: A question, In the `PieceType`, could I set `case empty = 1   case notEmpty = 2`  ? Is this okay?

Comment: Yes.. why not if  you want to specify value then you can but if you don't specify then it will by default value as ...case empty = 0 case notEmpty = 1