# Unarchive data report error: Thread 1:EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=EXC_BREAKPOINT, subcode=xxxx)

Tags: ios, swift, nskeyedunarchiver

When I archive my `data`, there come an `issue`, I never meet:

> [image: The issue]

The `thread` info:

```
 0xda5434 <+120>: bl     0xc7a6f0                  
; function signature specialization <preserving fragile attribute, 
Arg[1] = [Closure Propagated : reabstraction thunk helper from
 @callee_owned (@unowned Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>)
 -> () to @callee_owned (@unowned Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> 
(@out ()), Argument Types : [@callee_owned (@unowned Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>)
 -> ()]> of generic specialization <preserving fragile attribute,
 ()> of Swift.StaticString.withUTF8Buffer <A> ((Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> A) -> A
 ->  0xda5438 <+124>: trap
```

> The `console` log:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Part of my `userStatic`, the `archive` and `unarchive` data is `userStatic`:

```
import UIKit

enum UserType: Int {
case terant    
case normalUser   
case normalUserFinancialer  
}

@objc(UserStaticSwift)
class UserStaticSwift:NSObject, NSCoding {

//static let sharedInstance = UserStaticSwift()

var islogin: Bool = false   

var type:UserType? {

    didSet {
    
        if type == .terant {
            forOcType = 1
        }else if type == .normalUser {
        
            forOcType = 2
        }else {
            forOcType = 3
        }
    }
}
var forOcType:Int = 0   
var username:String = ""
var password:String = ""
var userId: String = ""   

// swiftSharedInstance is not accessible from ObjC
class var swiftSharedInstance: UserStaticSwift {
    struct UserStatic {
        static let instance = UserStaticSwift()
    }
    return UserStatic.instance
}

// the sharedInstance class method can be reached from ObjC
class func sharedInstance() -> UserStaticSwift {
    return UserStaticSwift.swiftSharedInstance
}

...
 // MARK: - coder
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init()

    islogin = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "islogin") as! Bool
    //type = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "type") as? UserType
    // type = UserType(rawValue: aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "type") as! Int)!
    /*if let type = UserTypeaDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("namesListArray") as? [String] {
        namesListArray = namesList
    } else {
        namesListArray = [String]
    }*/
    if let temp_type = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "type") as? Int {
        
        type = UserType(rawValue: temp_type )
    }else {
    
        type = nil
    }
    forOcType = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "forOcType") as! Int
    username = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "username") as! String
...

func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    
    aCoder.encode(islogin, forKey: "islogin")
    aCoder.encode(type!.rawValue, forKey: "type")
    aCoder.encode(forOcType, forKey: "forOcType")
    aCoder.encode(username, forKey: "username")
    aCoder.encode(password, forKey: "password")
    aCoder.encode(userId, forKey: "userId")
....

func addUserInfo(type:UserType, dic:[String: Any], closure:(Void)->Void) {
    

    if type == .terant {
        
        self.ter_status = UtilSwift.getIntFromAny(dic["status"] ?? "")
        self.ter_logo = UtilSwift.getStrFromAny(dic["logo"])
        self.ter_orgPhoto = UtilSwift.getStrFromAny(dic["orgPhoto"])
...
    
    closure()
}
```

The place `unarchive` data:

```
let paths:NSArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true) as NSArray
    let path = paths.firstObject
    let homePath = "\(path!)/\(Global.archive_userStaticData)"
    
    print("unarchive_path:\(homePath)")
    
    var userStatic:UserStaticSwift? = nil
    
    if let loaded:Any = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: homePath){
    
        userStatic = (loaded as? UserStaticSwift)!
    }else {
        
    }
    
    if userStatic == nil {
        
        return
    }
```

Someone occurs the same problem? I am clumsy to the `issue`, never meet the information.

Comment: Checkout my Answer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41116832/when-archive-object-in-the-func-encodewith-acoder-nscoder-method-crashed-with/41116908#41116908](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41116832/when-archive-object-in-the-func-encodewith-acoder-nscoder-method-crashed-with/41116908#41116908)

Comment: @jignesh Vadadoriya It is not the same thing, this question is `unarchive` caused., that is because of archive.

Comment: checkout my answer

Answer (score 0):

In `init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` method 
Try this

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    islogin = aDecoder.decodeBool(forKey: "islogin")
    forOcType = aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "forOcType") as! Int
    if let temp_type = aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "type") as? Int {

        type = UserType(rawValue: temp_type )
    }else {

        type = nil
    }

    username = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "username") as! String
    password = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "password") as! String
    userId = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "userId") as! String


}
```

i think it will help you

Comment: I do this in my code, you can see it in my question's code .

Comment: i have added decodeInteger this is not in your question.

Comment: for Bool value i have added decodeBool, fir Int value decodeInteger